# Return REST API response as an output claim to Azure B2C

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am currently developing a solution to add custom claims inside a JWT token.

The setup is as follows:

1. Azure B2C has a custom policy with multiple claims providers.
2. A claims provider for Azure AD is configured with standard claims and my custom one.
3. A claims provider for calling the REST API.
4. The REST API gathers is configured to gather custom attributes from the Graph API, it is configured to use an input claim of 'email' to lookup data related to the user logging in and an 'output' claim with the name of my custom claim.
5. A step has been added in the user `SignUpSignIn` journey to call the REST API before issuing the JWT token.

The user journey successfully works and I can redirect to Azure AD to authenticate. I can see the REST API being triggered from the logs in Azure and I get issued my JWT token, but I do not see the claim included whatsoever.

When I check the REST API logs, I can see that the function ran successfully and if I manually run the test option in my Azure Function, I can also see the successful response, which is a JSON array of data. So this would suggest that my REST API is working how it should be. I also tested it successfully from PowerShell and a Web Browser and got my response in the body correctly.

I have my suspicions that the problem lies in the process of returning the value and inserting it into the custom claim so that it appears in my JWT token.

FYI: The custom claim I am working with is to return the security groups a user is a memberOf in AzureAD.

```
<ClaimsProvider>
<DisplayName>REST API</DisplayName>
<TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="GetUserGroups">
  <DisplayName>Retrieves security groups assigned to the user</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://contoso.azurewebsites.net/api/aadgroups?code=123456789QWERTYUIOP123456789QWERTYUIOP==</Item>
    <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
    <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
    <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="restapigroups" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
</TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>

<ClaimType Id="restapigroups">
  <DisplayName>Group memberships</DisplayName>
  <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
  <UserHelpText>This is read only for the user</UserHelpText>
  <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
</ClaimType>

<OrchestrationStep Order="11" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserGroups" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GetUserGroups" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: An extra thing to mention is that I had tried to follow the claims transformation method as detailed below, but this was not successful and maybe not applicable:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/json-transformations#getclaimsfromjsonarray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must configure the RelyingParty section to output the claim into the Token. See this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-claims-exchange#add-the-claim

Comment: Do you mean the RelyingParty of the Azure AD claims provider?

The output claim is added in the REST API and Azure AD claims provider sections ("restapigroups")

```
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="restapigroups" />
```

Comment: Inn your signInOrSignUp.xml, you will have a section starting [<relyingparty>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/relyingparty#outputclaims). This configures which claims from your B2C claim bag are issued into the B2C token. You must add your output claim there. What you are describing is that you only output the claim to the claimbag, which is not enough.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I did forget to mention that the claim was already added in the SignUpOrSignIn.xml correctly.

I have just now managed to solve this issue and the problem was that I needed to add a reference claim type to the claim outputted in the JSON response. Once I did this, the claim outputted correctly. (PartnerClaimType="xxxxx")

Thank you for the support and help, we fixed it.

Comment: Ok sounds like your API to B2C claim mapping was incorrect, so B2C never had the claim in the claimbag. Glad its resolved.